# Is there a reason for an empty return statement at the end of void function?

Tags: c++, syntax, return

I was just looking at someone else's code and they have an empty return statement at the end of a void function:

```
void someFunction (int* someArg, int someArg2, int someArg3) {

    // some operations/function calls/recursion

    return;
}
```

Is there a particular reason why it should be there?

Comment: No, there's no reason, other than pure aesthetics.

Comment: If there wasn't a `return` at the end of the function, what would you expect it to do - hang?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason it *needs* to be there at the very end of a function, as far as I know. It's possible the function originally returned a value, someone changed it to a `void`, and just replaced `return value;` with `return;`. Or someone not very experienced with C++ assumed that every function **must** have a return, and will blindly believe this to the bitter end.

Now, a return in the middle of a function is definitely relevant since it stops the execution of the function at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it's nice to keep things explicit. Thus, I would prefer to use `return` in a `void` function. Whether you use it or not is up to you, but it helps with readability.

Answer (score -2):

In ISO/IEC 14882:2003 [Programming languages - C++] below.

> 6.6.3 The return statement
>
> 1. A function returns to its caller by the return statement.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If the return statement is not exist, a function can't return to caller. This is my understanding.

Comment: @StatusBreakPoint: Sorry, but your understanding is incorrect. A `return` is not required at the end of a `void` function. When execution reaches the end of the function it will return to the caller.